# Passing Id from one view to another when Button is clicked in Laravel 5.4

Tags: laravel-5

```
I am using response from xml server. I am trying to display the different detail view when each BUtton is pressed respectively.When the Button is pressed, I want to send the Id of each button to the detailed page and I want to display that Id on the detailed page too.


My Button for clicking and passing ID to next view respective to each button clicked is: 

 <a href='{{route('Detailed',["Id" => $flight["Id"]])}}'>SELECT NOW</a>  
$flight["Id"] is the response value that I get from the xml server
```

My route is for passing Id is: Id is what I want to pass from one view to another and display in second view

```
Route::get('/Detailed/{Id}',[ 
        'as' => 'Detailed', 'uses'=>'FlightController@show'
]);
```

My controller function to display is:
    public function show($Id)
    {}

It gives me error saying that:

```
Missing required parameters for [Route: Detailed] [URI: Detailed/{Id}] in view.blade.php. 
Please anyone help me

But if give direct value in button route 
such as ID value then,

<a href='{{route('Detailed',["Id" => "1234"])}}'>SELECT NOW</a>  

It works exactly what I expect.

Notes the Id value that I get is from simple_xml_response from server.
```

Comment: How are you retrieving the value for `$flight["Id"]`? Is it asynchronous? Can you try posting the result of `{{ $flight["Id"] }}` inside blade? It looks like you're trying to pass a null value. Also make sure to check the type of `$flight["Id"]`

Comment: It within the forloop . The id value comes like: "F!AMD!economy!{F!AMD!LGW!I147A!ACE!BA!BA!2732!O!!E!N!N!&F!AMD![!ACE!I19De!MAD!IB!I2!3857!!0!!"

Comment: I can see the results if if use {{ $flight["Id"] }} in blade template and also I have check with @if($flight["Id"] )  then got inside @endif. But getting same error

Comment: Try to enclose your $flight["Id"] inside double quotes as it is a string.

Comment: If i put within " ", then instead of displaying value , It displays same "$flight['id']", So I dont think it gonna work

Comment: If I use <a href='{{route('Detailed',["Id" => $flight->passenger["Id"]])}}'>SELECT NOW</a>   Then it works.  But I need to use main ID which is from $flight["ID"] value. I don't understand?

Comment: $flight["Id"] is an object type..

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

**Route**

```
Route::get('detailed/{id}', 'FlightController@show')->name('detailed');
```

**Controller**

```
public function show($id) {}
```

**Blade**

```
<a href='{{route('detailed', '1234')}}'>SELECT NOW</a>
```

Comment: This is where it gives me error: <a href='{{route('detailed', $flight["id"])}}'>SELECT NOW</a>   If i put '1234' directly it works.